# Is the Linear Program below unfeasible, unlimited or does it have an optimal solution? ...

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, simplex

> Is the Linear Program below unfeasible, unlimited or does it have an optimal solution? Properly justify your answer, making use of the dual program if it makes sense – if it doesn't, justify why

> \begin{align} max_{x_i}-x_1 + 5x_2 + 2x_3 - 7x_4 - x_5\\
> x_2 +  x_3 -  x_4       \geq 13\\
> x_1 - x_2 + 2x_4 + 2x_5 \leq 4\\
> x_2,x_4,x_5 \geq 0
> x_3 \geq -2\end{align}

I don't think there is a single viable solution, but I don't know how to continue. This is what i was able to do.

Primal \begin{align} max_{x_i}-x_1 + 5x_2 + 2x_3 - 7x_4 - x_5\\
x_2 +  x_3 -  x_4       \geq 13\\
-x_1 + x_2 - 2x_4 - 2x_5 \geq -4\\
x_2,x_4,x_5 \geq 0
x_3 \geq -2
\end{align}

Dual
\begin{align} min_{y_1,y_2}13y_1 - 4y_2 \\
0y_1 + y_2 \leq -1\\
 y_1 + y_2 \leq 5\\
 y_1 +0y_2 \leq 2\\
 y_1 +2y_2 \leq -7\\
0y_1 +2y_2 \leq -1\end{align}

$A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&1&0\\-1&1&0&2&2\\ \end{pmatrix}$

$b = (13,-4)^T$

$x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)^T$

$y = (y_1,y_2)^T$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is $x_1$ a free variable, namely $x_1\in \mathbb R$? And is $x_3\geq 0$ true?

Comment: I think $x_1$ is free. The exercise doesn't say anything about him. And as for the $x_3$ it's really wrong, thanks, the correct one is $x_3 \geq -2$.